# iTunes API App Store Keywords Search Volumes and Search Result Numbers

Tags: ios, itunes

I want to fetch the app store keywords search volumes and search result numbers data. But I cannot find the method and parameters.
I see the example from here:

https://searchman.com/ios/app/us/284882215/en/facebook-inc/facebook/?d=iPhone

"Volume" indicates the number of times this term is searched for by people using mobile devices with full internet browsers in each country.

"Hits" is the number of search results (apps) returned when you search with this term

I didn't find relate content from:
https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/

Anyone please kindly help me how to find them.